# Upload imagem utilizando ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Queria inserir uma imagem no servidor utilizando o AJAX. Já tentei faze-lo de várias maneiras mas não estou a conseguir enviar a imagem para o servidor. Se alguém conseguir uma solução, agradeço!

HTML

```
 <p>Imagem do Produto</p>
  <input type="file" id="prod_img" name="prod_img">

  <button id="add">ADICIONAR</button>
```

AJAX

```
$("#add").click(function(){ 
var prod_img = document.getElementById("prod_img").files[0].name;
 $.post('inserir.php',{prod_img:prod_img},
      function(data)
      {
        alert(data); 
       }
 });
});
```

PHP (inserir.php)

```
$prod_img = $_POST['prod_img'];

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO produtos (caminho_imagem) VALUES('$prod_img')";
if (!mysql_query($sql2))
{
  echo mysql_error();
}
else 
{ 
  $sourcePath = $_FILES['prod_img']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
  $targetPath = "imagens/".$_FILES['prod_img']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
  move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded file
  echo "Enviado"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa instanciar um objeto do tipo `FormData`, colocar o arquivo dentro dele e então referenciá-lo no `$.post`:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', document.getElementById("prod_img").files[0]);
    $.post('inserir.php', {
        data: formData
    }, function(data) {
        alert(data); 
    });
});
```

Comment: se fizer dessa maneira, o que `formData` irá conter será `[object FormData]`. Já agora aproveito para perguntar também o porque de se usar formData (nunca usei). Só se deve usar em cases de ficheiros?